# Showing a Group Can Be Totally Ordered

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, well-orders

If every finitely generated subgroup of a group $G$ is totally ordered, what approach should I take to prove that $G$ is also totally ordered?

Should I define a map that takes elements from the subgroups and make an ordering (I have no idea if this can even work, it was just an idea) or should I build a set that satisfies the four properties from this [page](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Totally_ordered_group) in its second paragraph?

Additionally, for such properties, what does it mean when it says $PP\subset P$?

Comment: $PP\subset P$ means that the product of two positive elements is positive. In general, $AB=\{ab:a\in A,\ b\in B\}$.

Comment: Do you know about ultrafilters?

Comment: @bof I read the Wikipedia page of it just now. Is this an easy way to prove the theorem? Do you have any ideas where to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to prove that for any two elements $a, b$, we have either $a\le b$ or $b\le a$. 
But this already holds in the subgroup generated by $a, b$ by hypothesis.

Having $P=\{x:x\ge e\}$, with $x, y\in P$ we get
$$xy\ \ge\ xe=x\ \ge\ e$$
so $xy\in P$, proving $PP\subseteq P$.

Similarly, if $x\in P\cap P^{-1}$, then both $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are $\ge e$, thus $e=xx^{-1}\ge xe=x\ge e$ yielding $e=x$.

If $x\ge e$, then $g^{-1}xg\ge g^{-1}eg=e$.

Finally, $P\cup P^{-1}=G$ expresses that the ordering is total.

Comment: Wow! Such an expert answer and very clear understanding! Thanks so much for the guidance.

Comment: Moreover, it's enough to assume that every *cyclic* subgroup is totally ordered. Can you prove that?

Comment: I suspect that the OP actually wants to prove that, if every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ admits an ordering compatible with the group structure, then so does $G$. In other words, no ordering relation is given, and the orderings of various subgroups can disagree with each other on the intersection of the subgroups. (That's a fairly standard application of the compactness theorem for propositional logic; hence bof's comment about ultrafilters.) In other words, I suspect the OP misstated the question so that a single relation on $G$ is already given.

Comment: Hmm.. That part was not clearly indicated in the question, but it indeed makes sense.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I do have to use the compactness theorem in my proof. Does that mean I have to use ultrafilters instead? I was just given only the definition of a totally ordered group and a total linear order on $G$.

Comment: If you know the compactness theorem, then you don't have to use ultrafilters. Ultrafilters could be used here instead of compactness, and they can also be used to prove the compactness theorem, but if you already have the compactness theorem then you might as well just use that.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see, I was just looking at your slides you made for Set Theory and Ultrafilters! Okay, I will use the compactness theorem, but I am stuck on what I should use the propositional variables for. That is why I asked this question, because I need to introduce variables and I am not sure what they should represent...That is why I thought using those properties would be okay, and I can set $p_{x,y}$ to represent an inequality possibly...

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. I'd use a propositional variable $p_{x,y}$ for each pair of elements of the given group $G$, with the intended "meaning" that $x\leq y$ in the ordering that I'm trying to construct. Any valuation (also called truth assignment) to these variables determines a binary relation $\leq$ on $G$: $x\leq y$ iff the valuation makes $p_{x,y}$ true. You need to produce a set $S$ of sentences such that whenever a valuation satisfies $S$, the corresponding relation $\leq$ makes $G$ a totally ordered group. (continued in next comment)

Comment: So if $S$ is satisfiable then $G$ is totally orderable. By compactness, it suffices to show that each finite subset of $S$ is satisfiable, and that's where you use the assumption that each finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is totally orderable.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Okay, I am very excited to take this approach! Thanks so much for taking the time and helping me, you made it very clear and understandable for me!